# Correction due to rounding error

Tags: self-study

The height for 1000 students is approximately normal with a mean 174.5cm and a standard deviation of 6.9cm. If 200 random samples of size 25 are chosen from this population and the values of the mean are recorded to the nearest integer, determine the probability that the mean height for the students is more than 176cm.

Since the samples were rounded to the nearest integer, I should find $P(X>176.5)$ instead of $P(X>176)$. Is this how we account for the effect of rounding the observations?

EDIT: In light of whuber's answer:

The answer given by my module (no workings were provided):

$\hspace{1cm} n=25; Normal$

$\hspace{1cm} \mu_{\overline{x}}=174.5cm$

$\hspace{1cm} \sigma_{\overline{x}}=6.9/5=1.38$

The answer is 0.1379. Which I'm pretty sure was found using $1-\phi(\dfrac{176-174.5}{1.38})$

So,

1. Is this an acceptable answer?
2. Since $n$ was less than 30, would it be ok to find the probability using a t-distribution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret this question as supposing that an experiment is conducted 200 times.  In this experiment, 25 people are independently drawn from the population (with replacement) and their average height is rounded to the nearest centimeter.  This process yields 200 whole numbers.  You seem to be asking, what is the chance that the average of these 200 numbers exceeds 176 cm.

This interpretation requires us to deal with several phenomena: the sampling distribution of the mean, the effects of rounding, and the effect of repeated sampling.  Other interpretations are possible but it appears these issues will arise no matter what, so I hope the following analysis will illustrate useful, relevant techniques even if a different interpretation is intended.

---

The **sampling distribution of the mean** of 25 independent values (with replacement) has the same mean as the parent distribution and 1/25th of its variance.  It's also Normal.  Thus in this case it's a Normal(174.5, 6.9/5) distribution.

**Rounding** turns a continuous distribution (Normal(174.5, 6.9/5) in this case) into a *discrete* distribution, because now the only possible values are 0, 1, ..., 174, 175, 176, ..., cm.  The probability of observing one of these values $y$ equals the probability that the true value lies between $y - 1/2$ and $y + 1/2$ and therefore is given by

$$\Pr(Y) = \Phi(\frac{y + 1/2 - 174.5}{6.9/5}) - \Phi(\frac{y - 1/2 - 174.5}{6.9/5}).$$

where, as usual, $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function for the standard Normal distribution.

Because normal distributions are symmetric, bias in rounding of values less than the mean ought to balance any bias in rounding of values greater than the mean.  The balancing will be perfect when the distribution's mode is a half integer, which is the case here.  Thus the mean of this "discrete Normal" distribution is *exactly* 174.5.

**The rounding will increase the variance**.  *As an approximation,* people usually think of rounding as acting *at random* to vary a number by some amount uniformly distributed between $-1/2$ and $+1/2$.  The variance of this uniform distribution is $1/12$, whence we can *estimate* the variance of the discrete normal distribution as

$$\sqrt{sd^2 + 1/2} = \sqrt{(6.9/5)^2 + 1/12} = 1.40986\ 99703\ 63697\ 52354,$$

approximately.  This approximation works well when the rounding is small compared to the standard deviation of the true distribution, which is the case here.  In fact, exact calculations give a value of $1.40986\ 99703\ 63697\ 65285$, differing from the approximation by about $10^{-16}$.  That's more than accurate enough! -- But it was worthwhile checking.

Now that we know the parameters of the distribution of rounded averages of 25-person samples--namely, a mean of 174.5 and SD of 1.40986--we determine as before that the expectation of **the mean of 200 such rounded averages** is 174.5 and its SD is $1.40986/\sqrt{200}$ = $0.099693$.  Now this distribution is going to be extremely close to Normal, but not perfectly so: after all, its values must all be multiples of 1/200 = 0.005 cm.  If you like, you can introduce a **continuity correction** in the usual way by observing that there can be no average between 176 and 176.005 cm, so you would compute the probability of a *Normal* variate exceeding their midpoint of 176.0025 cm.  However, this makes no practical difference, because 176 - 174.5 cm is more than 15 standard deviations above the mean: it's virtually impossible that the average of 200 rounded values could exceed either 176.0025 or 176.  The exact value is approximately

$$1 - \Phi(\frac{176.0025 - 174.5}{0.099693})$$

which less than $10^{-53}$.  Because the original population is only "approximately" Normal, we shouldn't rely on any probability calculation this small.  We might just as well say **the answer is "essentially zero."**

Comment: (+1) I like this answer. It took some time to me, but it seems I have been missing something in the question (*200 random samples* of size 25 each).

Comment: @chl Thank you. This one's open to some interpretation. In light of a related question, the OP might be fishing for the use of a finite population correction term, which I didn't mention at all (http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5158/919). What interests me most is the effect of rounding; everything else is routine. In some cases (not this one!) rounding has a pronounced effect (both as a bias and a variance inflator), so it's nice to be able to present a simple example of how one can evaluate that effect. Actually I'm amazed the effect is so small in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the question as one where we know the theoretical distribution of students height with some precision (i.e., with one decimal place). In the present case, this is a gaussian distribution with parameters $\mathcal{N}(174.5;6.9^2)$.

Now, we have empirical measurements of students height on small samples ($n=25$), but results are rounded to the nearest integer due to possible measurement error or imperfect measurement device.

So, my understanding is that the question is really to assess $\Pr(X>176)$ or $\Pr(Z>\frac{176-174.5}{6.9})$ if you refer to the standardized $\mathcal{N}(0;1)$ distribution, and not $\Pr(X>176.5)$ as you suggested.

Comment: **This response seems essentially wrong** as I forgot about the sampling issue.