# Chi-square test where sample is the population

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample, population

I have Likert-scale survey data in which the sample is 97% of the population (181 out of a possible 188 respondents). I have tried to follow the complex debate about the need and value of statistical inference tests when the sample is the population in the Cross Validated posts below (and elsewhere):

[Statistical inference when the sample "is" the population](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/statistical-inference-when-the-sample-is-the-population)

[Is chi-squared necessary if comparing entire populations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284522/is-chi-squared-necessary-if-comparing-entire-populations)

[Does it make sense to compute confidence intervals and to test hypotheses when data from whole population is available?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68886/does-it-make-sense-to-compute-confidence-intervals-and-to-test-hypotheses-when-d)

I have now lost confidence in my thinking: a chi-square test seemed an obvious choice for me (2x5 table with ordinal data), although I am far from an expert statistician. My questions are:

- Does it matter that my sample size virtually equals my population size when running a chi-square test?
- Will the p-value be meaningful (ie can I consider the results in the usual way)?
- Should I rather just do a correlation co-efficient to search out relationships since I don't need to infer from my sample to the population?

I would value any assistance, direction or being sent on to links where I can learn more.

Comment: Are you really only interested in those 188 people? What if 189 people said they would do it?

Comment: To put it a different way, exactly what do you mean by "possible" respondents and "population"? If you can't clarify that, perhaps describe the actual population and your interest in their responses.

Comment: Or to put it yet another way: do you only care about the results for those 188 people, or do you want to be able to generalize your results to other people similar to those 188?

Comment: Thank you for the questions, very helpful. The 188 are the total number of registered learners in a set of classes being surveyed; so I've seen this as my "population". But looking at your questions perhaps I should rethink my definition?