# A/B test and SRS

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, sampling

I was reading about Simple Random Sampling (SRS) from [this lecture notes](http://www.mit.edu/~6.s085/notes/lecture7.pdf). It says that SRS, which actually is a sampling *without replacement* makes $x_i$ not independent.

Then I thought about A/B testing. When doing A/B testing for a product feature, usually users are sampled randomly *without replacement*, put in one of two buckets, and only one group will see the feature. Also, usually I analyse the result using t-test, which assumes independence of samples.

Is this a problem and what should be the workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The author is talking about a [finite sample correction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5158/176202). When A/B testing, the population is rather large, unless you have some website that is only accessible to only a limited number of people, so the correcting factor:

$$\frac{N-n}{N-1}$$

tends to $1$ and can be ignored, as long as the sample you draw for A/B testing ($n$) is supposedly smaller than the population of potential visitors to your site ($N$). Even if the sample was large compared to the population, how would you go about determining the population size of potential visitors to your website?

If anything, [the usual unbiased estimator of variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3931/176202) has a larger denominator ($\frac{1}{n-1}$) than the finite-sample corrected version. In other words, the worst case scenario is an overestimation of the variance, resulting in slightly less power.

Answer (score 0):

As a practitioner, I am thinking about this too. We need to figure out what is population/sample in each scenario and what is our estimand. Here is my conclusion:

- In Two Sample T-tests Scenario:

  We have 2 populations and draw 2 srs samples to compare population
  mean. Since our sample is srs, each sample is an unbiased represent
  of corresponding population, we use sample mean/variance to estimate
  population mean/variance and perform T-tests.
- In A/B Testing Scenario:

  We split users into 2 arms(control and treatment), and want to compare the mean difference of 2 arms. Thus, **each arm itself is
  a population**, instead of a srswor sample from total users. So we do not need to use finite sample correction to estimate means' population variance.