# What is the formula of the finite population correction factor?

Tags: sampling, finite-population

Is it (N-n)/N or (N-n)/(N-1)? Provided that they can be used interchangeably, why would you use one instead of the other?

Comment: To the extent that chl's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-correction-factor) covers this question (even though the question is a little different), I guess this counts as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The term $\frac{N-n}{N-1}$ is a term in the variance of a [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

If you use the binomial variance instead (substituting $K/N$ for $p$), then the terms are the same *aside from this term*.

Thus you *could* think of this term as a way of adjusting a variance calculated under an assumption of binomial sampling (in effect, sampling without replacement, or sampling from an infinite population) for the fact that you're actually sampling with replacement from a finite population.

Under the assumptions relevant for these formulas to apply in their respective cases, the $\frac{N-n}{N}$ version could be seen as an approximation, but if $N$ and $n$ are reasonably large then that will make very little difference (and even less difference again once you convert to a standard deviation).

(However there are other ways to argue for the N denominator besides as an approximation.)