# Maximum sample size for one-way ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, assumptions, approximation, mathematical-statistics

Lists of requirements for [one-way ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance) include the following:

- Samples should be mutually independent
- Samples should be from a population with a normal distribution
- Samples should have the same variance (though if the max standard deviation is less than twice the smallest, it's "close enough")
- The samples should be simple random samples from their population (according to [*Sullivan*, 5ed](https://www.pearson.com/store/p/statistics-informed-decisions-using-data/P100002447436/9780134133539), pg. 620; though Wikipedia seems to [disagree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance#Assumptions))

Many statistical analyses (e.g. Student's *t*-test) require that a sample's size be small relative to its population (often, $n \le 0.05 N$ is used as a rule of thumb). This allows individuals within a given sample to be treated as approximately independent of each other.

I am curious why the $n \le 0.05 N$ requirement doesn't appear in the list for ANOVA. **Is the assumption/approximation of a small sample size relative to the population size at all relevant to ANOVA?** If so, how is it relevant? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *n < 0.05N* rule of thumb is with regards to applying a finite population correction factor (FPC) for estimating a standard error. You are correct that just about any analysis, in which you have sampled a sizable proportion of the finite population, will have a smaller true standard error than the one estimated under the assumption that N is infinite. Just do the thought experiment where you ask "what should my standard error be when n=N?" If your answer is 0, then an FPC adjustment may be appropriate.

There is a good discussion of the FPC in this thread.
[Explanation of finite correction factor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-correction-factor)

In many settings we think of N being infinite, so the FPC does not apply.

Comment: Neat! Thanks. Why is it not used for ANOVA then?

Comment: Methodological development for the analysis of survey data has extended finite population corrections to additional settings.