# Optimum sample size for a large population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to identify what should be the optimum sample for a population. Based on various articles. I identified that there is a formula that helps to calculate that , based on Confidence Level, Confidence Interval and variance.

However, what I is confusing is that for a set value of Confidence Level, Confidence Interval and variance,  we get the same sample size irrespective of the population size after a certain point based on the formula.

Could anyone kindly let me know if I am understanding it correctly or not. Also, how does the population size have no effect on the sample size after a certain point? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I won't consider your question to be a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5158/247274), but it's related.

Comment: You're right that in sample size calculations for finite populations once the population is large enough that it is many times the size of the sample, the population size hardly matters at all -- it converges pretty quickly to be essentially the same as the case for an infinite population, where variance of sample estimates is only impacted by sample size and not at all affected by sampling fraction (sample size divided by population size). Can you clarify what aspect of these issues is leading to confusion?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your response. I am new to statistics, so I was just confused about how population has no impact on the sample. Say I need to find out what percentage of the population of a country has taken a vaccine. So If I am to consider a sample size for this, I can  see that based on the formula there is no change after 100000. As such I am trying to wrap my head around the fact that sample size is ~385, irrespective of the fact whether the population is 100000 or 10000000.

Comment: You haven't told us how you are calculating the sample size (via software, a website or what?).
All comments and the answer below suggest that you have a noticeable finite population for the smaller populations sizes. I hope that you did read the post linked by @Dave above.

Comment: @stweb- I am using the formula to calculate the sample size. Also, I did go through the answer, but doesnot explain what the sample size should be and why the sample size does not increase after population increases after a certain point. Do you have any literature or link which gives more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations you're reading assume an infinite population, sometimes called a data-generating process (DGP), though this term is a bit loose. The gist is that a DGP can be sampled from as many times as one wants, such as flipping a coin over and over and over and over. In this case, "population" is a convenient way to represent to newcomers the idea of a distribution in mathematics.

There are, however, [results for finite-size populations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5158/247274), though I would consider such a case to be the exception in most areas of statistics (certainly in what I do).