# Calculating the confidence interval from survey data with a small population

Tags: confidence-interval

I sent out a survey to 118 people, which is the entire population of interest. I received 22 responses.

I'm using these results to show a distribution of responses. For example, the survey answers range from "strongly disagree" to "strongly agree". I don't care as much about the mean or any summary statistics as I do about the distribution of these responses along that agreement scale.

I have two questions:

1. Given that I'm not compiling any summary statistics, does it make sense to create any kind of confidence interval around the results that I'm sharing? For example, 25% of respondents marked "strongly disagree". Should I provide some kind of error margin around that stat to reflect how it might be applied to the population as a whole?
2. If I do create a confidence interval, how can I factor in my small finite population size?

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

When you are sampling without replacement and the size of your sample is quite large relative to the population, you can use the finite population correction. This involves multiplying the standard error in your confidence interval by a factor of
$$ \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}},$$
where $n$ is the sample size and $N$ is the population size.

There's a detailed explanation in this issue: [Explanation of finite population correction factor?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-population-correction-factor)

The main thing I would worry about in your case is self-selection bias, i.e. the fact that there is no guarantee that the people who did not respond have similar opinions to those who did respond.