# How to calculate TOTAL stratified sample size given the strata sizes, means and standard deviations, for a 95% confidence level?

Tags: sampling, experiment-design

I am trying to find the formula/method of computing the total sample size for a stratified population, given this information:

```
Stratum | size | mean | SD
Large   | 200  | 60   | 15
Small   | 400  | 10   | 5
```

The problem statement is as follows, nothing more:

> "A stratified sampling of (companies) is going to be made.The necessary information regarding the sampling is: [table]. The volume of this sample, calculated for a 95% (z=1.96) confidence level and a maximum allowable error of +- 1 from the mean is: [blank answer space]."

The answer key says 222 and so does [this calculator](https://stattrek.com/survey-sampling/sample-size-calculator), split 148-74, but I have had no luck finding any formulas relating to this in the exam books or how the calculator gets those values.

Comment: Welcome to CV, p-3265! Is this a homework question / are you preparing for an exam / trying to learn by yourself? Then consider using the [`self-study`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag to get help understanding the matter. The key word you need for [searching on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stratified+allocation) or google is "allocation" or "optimal allocation"

Comment: There are various different formulas depending on the costs of obtaining samples from each stratum.  Presumably you need to minimize the standard error of the mean estimate subject to the constraints and, again presumably, subject to requiring that estimator to be unbiased.  It therefore would help us to know which of these unstated assumptions we need to be making.

Comment: Hi @whuber, thank you for the reply and explanation. Unfortunately there is no additional information provided by the statement. Word for word:


"A stratified sampling of (companies) is going to be made.The necessary information regarding the sampling is: [table].
The volume of this sample, calculated for a 95% (z=1.96) confidence level and a maximum allowable error of +- 1 from the mean is: [blank answer space]."

That is all there is unfortunately, apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Hi @Ute, thank you for the tips. I have checked the CV posts you linked and other sources, but unfortunately I'm no wiser :(. I have learned how to allocate the stratas by the various (equal/proportional/optimal) allocations, but I struggle relating these to the scenario above, i.e. finding that sample size using a confidence level and a maximum allowable error of 1. My attempts have yet to yield the elusive "n=222" and I've almost reached the point of giving up, hence my question.

Comment: reverse-engineering from the answer, it seems that your book actually does not do optimal allocation, but [*proportional allocation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling#Stratified_sampling_strategies) (sry). The [Wikipedia page on stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling#Mean_and_standard_error) has a formula that allows you to calculate the standard error of the mean. You need to set the +-1 equal to +- 1.96*standard error. Then solve for $n$ (prop. allocation: $n_h=n\cdot N_h/N$)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Ute. I understand the general approach, but how would I compute the SE given that I only have the sizes of the strata, not the number of observations in each stratum? It feels a bit like a loop of needing the sample size to allocate the n_h and the n_h to compute the sample size :(

Comment: You know the ratio $N_h/N$, so if you knew $n$, you would also have $n_h$. You also know the $s_h$. With this, you can write the formula for SE such that the only unknown is $n$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

**The answers given in the question are not wrong, but they are substantially worse than the best possible ones.**  This post explains the sense of "best," derives a general solution, and illustrates it with the data in the question.

---

The two strata are populations of sizes $N_1 = 200$ and $N_2 = 400$ with means $\mu_1 = 60$ and $\mu_2 = 10$ and standard deviations $\sigma_1 = 15$ and $\sigma_2 = 5,$ respectively.

If we take samples $\mathbf X = (X_i)$ from the first population of size $K_1$ and $\mathbf Y = (Y_j)$ of size $K_2$ from the second population *without replacement,* we would estimate $\mu_1$ from the sample mean $\bar X$ and $\mu_2$ from the sample mean $\bar Y.$  From these an unbiased estimate of the population mean is obtained by converted the means to *totals* and back again, giving

$$t(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y) = \frac{N_1 \bar X + N_2 \bar Y}{N_1 + N_2}.$$

(From now on the stratum means are irrelevant: the optimal sample size does not depend on what we might suppose the means to be or even on what they actually are.)

Our thread at [Explanation of finite population correction factor?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158) presents multiple derivations of the standard error of a sample without replacement: it shows that

$$\operatorname{Var}(\bar X) = \frac{N_1 - K_1}{K_1(N_1 - 1)}\sigma^2_1$$

and similarly for $\bar Y.$  Consequently

$$\operatorname{se}_t^2 = \operatorname{Var}(t(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y)) = \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\left(N_1^2\frac{N_1 - K_1}{K_1(N_1 - 1)}\sigma^2_1 +  N_2^2\frac{N_2 - K_2}{K_2(N_2 - 1)}\sigma^2_2\right). $$

Its standard error is the square root of this quantity, $\operatorname{se}_t.$

---

**The question asks us to find $K_1$ and $K_2$ for which $1.96 \operatorname{se}_t\le 1.$**  There is *always* a solution because exhaustive sampling -- $K_1 = N_1$ and $K_2=N_2$ -- reduces the standard error to zero. Evidently, in general, there are *many* solutions, because upon finding one we could just keep increasing $K_1$ and $K_2,$ which can only reduce this standard error.

We usually exploit this by finding *the least expensive sample size* that meets the precision criterion.  Assuming it's equally expensive to sample from each population and that the overhead of sampling is fixed, the cost is proportional to the total sample size $K_1+K_2.$  This leads to an optimization problem:

> Find integers $0\le K_1\le N_1$ and $0\le K_2\le N_2$ for which $K_1+K_2$ is as small as possible subject to the constraint $Z_{\alpha/2}\operatorname{se}^2_t \le 1$

where $Z_{\alpha/2} = 1.96$ is the upper $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard Normal distribution when $\alpha = 100\% - 95\%.$

Looking at the formula with an eye towards simplification, notice that the squared standard error is really a linear function of the reciprocal sample sizes $1/K_i:$

$$\operatorname{se}_t^2 + \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\left(\frac{N_1^2\sigma_1^2}{N_1-1} + \frac{N_2^2\sigma_2^2}{N_2-1} \right) = \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\left(\frac{N_1^3 \sigma_1^2}{N_1 - 1}\,\color{red}{\frac{1}{K_1}} + \frac{N_2^3 \sigma_2^2}{N_2 - 1}\,\color{red}{\frac{1}{K_2}} \right). $$

Thus, the constraint on $\operatorname{se}^2_t$ is really a constraint on the right hand side of this equation which we may express as $\lambda_1/K_1 + \lambda_2/K_2$ where the $\lambda_i$ are positive numbers computed from the population sizes and variances,

> $$\lambda_i = \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\left(\frac{N_i^3 \sigma_i^2}{N_i - 1} \right).$$

The right hand side cannot exceed $\beta$ where

> $$\beta= \left(\frac{1}{Z_{\alpha/2}}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\left(\frac{N_1^2\sigma_1^2}{N_1-1} + \frac{N_2^2\sigma_2^2}{N_2-1} \right).$$

The optimization problem thereby is reduced to the simple

> Find integers $K_i$ of minimal sum subject to the constraints $0\le K_i\le N_i$ and $\lambda_1/K_1 + \lambda_2/K_2 \le \beta.$

This is not easy to solve, but Calculus gives us a very good approximate solution by varying the $K_i$ among all *real* numbers instead of just integers.  The method of Lagrange multipliers (or, if you prefer elementary but belabored algebra) tells us an optimum is found where the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(-\lambda_1/K_1^2, -\lambda_2/K_2^2)$ are multiples of each other.  Equivalently, $K_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_2/\lambda_1}K_1.$  That reduces the problem to the single variable $K_1$ where the constraint reduces to

$$\beta\ge \frac{\lambda_1}{K_1} + \frac{\lambda_2}{K_2} = \frac{\lambda_1 + \sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{K_1},$$

with solution

> $$K_1 \ge \frac{\lambda_1 + \sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\beta},\quad K_2 =  \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}}\,K_1.$$

*I suspect most sample size calculators simply round this Calculus solution to the nearest integer.*  That can actually be far from the optimal solution in terms of the distance in the $(K_1,K_2)$ plane, but it will be very close in terms of overall sample size.

Those seeking understanding rather than the mere application of a formula will appreciate that the $\lambda_i$ will be closely approximated by $N_i^2\sigma_i^2,$ whence the optimum allocation is essentially proportional to both the *relative population size* $N_2/N_1$ and the *relative standard deviation* $\sigma_2/\sigma_1.$  The larger and more variable strata deserve relatively larger samples.

---

In the question, we may compute

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\frac{N_1^3\sigma_1^2}{N_1-1} = \frac{1}{600^2}\frac{200^3 15^2}{200-1} = 25.1256,$$

$$\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{(N_1+N_2)^2}\frac{N_2^3\sigma_2^2}{N_2-1} = \frac{1}{600^2}\frac{400^3 5^2}{400-1}  = 11.1390,$$

and

$$\beta= \left(\frac{1}{1.96}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{600^2}\left(\frac{200^2 15^2}{200-1} + \frac{400^2 5^2}{400-1} \right) = 0.41378.$$

The optimum (among real numbers) is attained at

$$K_1^* = \frac{\lambda_1 + \sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\beta}= \frac{25.1256 + \sqrt{25.1256\times 11.1390}}{0.41378} = 101.15$$

and

$$K_2^* = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}} K_1^* = \sqrt{\frac{11.1390}{25.1256}} 101.15 = 0.6658 \times 101.15 = 67.35.$$

A calculator would likely round both these values up to be safe, calling for samples of size $102$ in stratum 1 and $68$ in stratum 2 for a total cost of $170$ samples.  But in this instance we may reduce either of these sample sizes (but not both) by $1$ and still have a solution with $169$ samples.

---

The solution quoted in the question calls for $222$ samples, or 30% more, divided into a ratio of $148:74$ = $400:200.$  Evidently it just *assumes* the sample size in each stratum will be proportional to the stratum size and then finds the smallest total sample size that meets the objective (which it does).  This example demonstrates the cost of this (often poor) approach: the sampling budget is 30% greater than it needs to be.

The reason for the better performance of the optimal solution developed here is that a good sampling program ought to account for differences in the *variability* within each stratum: strata with relatively low variability (that is, smaller standard deviations) don't need large samples to be precisely characterized.  Good sampling designs therefore will account for such differences.