What is the correct sample size for the purposes of this test?
$X_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n_X$, are i.i.d. from some distribution; and $Y_j$, $j = 1, \ldots, n_Y$, are i.i.d. from some other distribution. Consider all pairs $(X_i, Y_j)$. The number of pairs is $n=n_X n_Y$​.
$k$ of these pairs fulfill the condition: $X_i > Y_j$. I want to test whether the probability $p$ of a pair fulfilling the condition is different from a known probability $p_0$​.
My initial thought is to perform an exact binomial test (e.g., binom.test() in R) or a 1-sample proportions test (e.g., prop.test() in R) with arguments $k$ successes, $n$ trials, and $p_0$​ null probability. However, setting the number of trials for this test to $n$ seems incorrect. For example, if $n_X = n_Y = 10$, then $n = 100$, which doesn't seem like the correct sample size.
My intuition suggests that the number of trials should be adjusted, perhaps to something like $\sqrt{n_X n_Y}$​​, and consequently, the number of successes should be adjusted to $k n^{−1} \sqrt{n_X n_Y}​$​​. However, other than intuition, I have no clue.
What is the correct way to perform this test?

You may want to look at this question; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638812/mann-whitney-u-test-compared-to-binomial-test . The major issue is that the pair-wise comparisons are not independent; imagine you sorted all your $x_i$ and $y_j$, so that $x_1$ is the lowest. Then if $x_t>y_u$, it will also be true for all $i>t$ and all $j<u$. So the binomial test is not valid; and I doubt that simply "adjusting" the sample size will fix this. What you are trying to do is compare the Hodges–Lehmann estimator to a fixed value; not sure if such a test exists?

Are you after analytic result or after a numeric estimate? If it is the latter, it might be much easier to simulate it. Get X-samples and then Y-samples from the known distribution. Compute $k$ for this draw. Repeat, keep repeating until you have a distribution of $k$, then simply read the probability for your particular pair from the distribution.
